# SQL select only number in coulomb price

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have these values in table `price`:

**price**

```
1- 500000.00 $
2-15222215.22 $
3-158684663.23 €
```

How can I only extract numbers from this column?

Comment: The coulomb (named after Charles-Augustin de Coulomb, unit symbol: C) is the SI unit of electric charge (symbol: Q or q), defined as the charge transported by a constant current of one ampere in one second...

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can do mysql's silent conversion as

```
mysql> select ('15222215.22 $')+0;
+---------------------+
| ('15222215.22 $')+0 |
+---------------------+
|         15222215.22 |
+---------------------+
```

Other way is using `substring_index`

```
mysql> select substring_index(trim('500000.00 $'),' ',1) as num;
+-----------+
| num       |
+-----------+
| 500000.00 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @currency varchar(50) = '1- 500000.00 $'

SET @currency = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@currency, CHARINDEX('-', @currency, 1) + 1, LEN(@currency)))

SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@currency, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @currency, 1) - 1))
```